# Closed Formula For $\sum_{i =1}^{n}(n-i)\cdot 2^{i-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, exponential-function

I had tried to find the closed formula for $$\sum_{i =1}^{n}(n-i)\cdot 2^{i-1}$$ combinatorially following algorithm:

$$\sum_{i =1}^{n}(n-i)\cdot 2^{i-1} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i =1}^{n}(n-i)\cdot 2^{i}. $$

$1.$ $2^i$ represent total number of subset of $[i]$.

$2.$ $(n-i)$ represent the whole possible cases of choosing one elment among $[n-i]$

Considering the $1.$ and $2$. same time, $1/2\cdot\sum_{i =1}^{n}(n-i)\cdot 2^{i} $ represents among ordered $n$ elements $1,2,3,4...,n$, choose fist $i$ element and put them into a set. Then among the rest of them choose another one to put it into the same set. Then multiply $1/2$ which reduces the duplicated counting to represent "total number of subsets of [n] which contains at least one element in it"

Therefore, the answer is $2^{n-1}-1$.

Is this algorithm logically clear?

---

add: Reference to comments, the answer is $2^n - n - 1$ which corresponds to the number of total subset with size more than 2

How could one relate this fact to the given summation?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi+%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D(n-i)%5Ccdot+2%5E%7Bi-1%7D) disagrees.

Comment: $\sum (n-i)2^{i-1}=n\sum 2^{i-1}-\sum i2^{i-1}$. Can you relate the second term with differentiation of $\sum x^i$ or note that $\sum i2^{i-1}=\sum_i\sum_{j\leq i} 1\cdot 2^{i-1}$

Comment: @MANMAID I prefer to be combintorial way to prove this theorem but I will try your recommendation right now

Comment: Your combinatorial argument is a little short. You indeed explain you to form the LHS, but the link to the RHS is not very clear.

Comment: How about out of [1], [2], [3], ... I always choose 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x+x^2+...+x^n$.

Thus, $$f'x)=1+2x+...+nx^{n-1}=\left(\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right)'=\frac{((n+1)x^n-1)(x-1)-(x^{n+1}-x)}{(x-1)^2}.$$
Hence,
$$1+2\cdot2+3\cdot2^2+...+n2^{n-1}=(n+1)\cdot2^n-1-2^{n+1}+2=(n-1)2^n+1.$$
Id est,
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(n-i)2^{i-1}=n\cdot\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}-(n-1)2^n-1=$$
$$=n(2^n-1)-(n-1)2^n-1=2^n-n-1.$$

Comment: What does "Id est," mean?

Comment: @MrYouMath Id est=i.e.

Comment: but OP wants a combinatorial argument I guess.(I did not downvote)

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, you are right. Now I see it. I hope that my solution will help.

Comment: By your formula if $n=4$ then $3+2×2+2^2=4(2^4-1)-2^4-1 \implies 3+4+4=4(16-1)-16-1 \implies 11=4×15-17 \implies 11=60-17 \implies 11=43$

Comment: Sorry, i saw you just edited

Comment: @neonpokharkar Thank you!

Comment: I had followed your answer. Is it enough to be called "combinatoric"? I know there's some element of it but can't be sure of whether it's combinatoric way of understanding or not.

Comment: @Beverlie My solution is a solution without combinatoric, but at least you know now the answer.

Comment: Your answer is beautiful not at least but sufficiently is.

Comment: @Beverlie Thank you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As you say in your answer, $$2^n-(n+1)=|X=\{A\subseteq [n]:|A|>2\}|,$$
where $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots , n\}.$ Now, consider the following sets $$A_i = \{A\subseteq[n]:i\in A,\exists ! j\in A\text{ s.t } i<j\}.$$
So, for choosing $j$ we have $(n-i)$ possibilities because those are the numbers greater than $i.$ Also, perhaps $A$ contains elements less than $i,$ so to choose them we can do it in $2^{i-i}$ ways, so $$|A_i| = (n-i)2^{i-1},$$
now check that the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint and use the sum principle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n-i=k$$$$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k\cdot 2^{n-k}$$$$$$
$$2S= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k\cdot 2^{n-k}$$$$$$

> $$2S= 2^{n-1} + 2× 2^{n-2} + 3× 2^{n-3}+\cdots +(n-2) ×2^2 +(n-1)× 2$$$$$$
>   Dividing both sides by 2,
>   $$S=2^{n-2} +2 ×2^{n-3} +3 ×2^{n-4} +\cdots + (n-2)× 2 + (n-1)$$
>   $$$$

Now $2S -S$ gives us$$$$
$$S=2^{n-1} +2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+\cdots +2^2+2-(n-1)$$$$$$
Using GM formula,
$$S=2 \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2-1} -(n-1)$$$$$$
$$S=2^{n} -2 -n +1$$$$$$
$$S= 2^n-(n+1)$$$$$$

Comment: but OP wants a combinatorial argument I guess.(I did not downvote)

Comment: He said he prefers combinatorial argument